# VB - Set property in linq to sql to this instance

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, select, properties

So I'm writing a program to build family trees. I have a class named "Person" and a class "Birth". Both classes have a property which is an instance of the other class; a "Person"-object has a property containing that persons birth, and a "Birth"-object has a property containing the child whose birth it is. In a mapper which extracts persons from my Database, I wrote the following (shortend):

```
Friend Class PersonRepository

Shared db As New DatabaseDataContext

Function GivePerson(ByVal ID As Integer) As Person
    Return (From person In db.tbl_persons 
    Where person.ID = ID 
    Select New Person With 
    {
        .Birth = (From birth In db.tbl_births
                  Where birth.KidID = ID
                  Select New Birth With{
                      .Kid = Me
                  }).ToList.FirstOrDefault
    }).ToList.FirstOrDefault

End Function

End Class
```

I figured as much that this wasn't going to work, so I think I solved it by creating two separate object and then set each others properties, like this:

```
Friend Class PersonRepository

Shared db As New DatabaseDataContext

Function GivePerson(ByVal ID As Integer) As Person
    Dim per = (From person In db.tbl_persons 
    Where person.ID = ID 
    Select New Person With 
    {
        .ID = person.ID
    }).ToList.FirstOrDefault

    Dim bir = (From birth In db.tbl_births
               Where birth.KidID = ID
               Select New Birth With{
                   .ID = birth.ID
               }).ToList.FirstOrDefault
    bir.Kid = per
    per.Birth = bir
    Return per
End Function
End Class
```

1. Am I going about this the right way?
2. Can you refer to the object which you're creating in the creation of a property of that object?

I recently picked up programming again, so I might make a very beginners mistake, in which case I'm sorry.

Comment: I would like to view a persons information (name, birth, death, relations, ...) which would contain his/her birth details. At the other hand, I would also like to view a Birth as an Event, which has several properties of its own (person, date, location, attendants, ...). I don't know if this is in some way a violation to OO programming.

Comment: You can reference an object during its creation, but only from inside its constructor